# htaccess rewrite url, add dir and remove query

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two versions of images on my server, one with and one without a watermark. On my one website I want to have to non-watermarked version. On the websites that hotlink my images I want to have the ones with the watermark.

I want to rewrite the url to serve the watermarked images on those website. The url structure on my website is this:
www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/image-name.jpg?t=1512472796

and I want to change it to:
www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/**wm**/image-name.jpg

I am kind of stuck here, no idea to do the part that adds the wm dir to the url and removes the query:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=([0-9]*)$
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to rewrite referer url from `www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/ wm/image-name.jpg` to `www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/image-name.jpg?t=1512472796` ? Is the query perameter `t=1512472762` same on all urls?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Have been too busy... No, I want to write it the way I wrote above, so adding the wm directory and removing the query. The query is dynamic. Thanks for your efforts.